Uploading certain columns of multiple CSV files in R and putting them into a data frame
So I'm having trouble working this out. I have multiple CSV files with the same two columns: Wavenumber and Intensity. The Wavenumber column for each file is the exact same, so I don't really care about that one. Is there a way to extract the Intensity column from every CSV file and put them all into a data frame? I've found a few answers for using one CSV file, but nothing for multiple.
I've tried using list.files and lapply with fread, but that makes a list of data frames of the CSV files, which could work, but I eventually need to graph these against each other.
Here's what the list of data frames looks like:
$`file_name_1`
   Wavenumber  Intensity
   <num>       <num>
1: 648.5568    1.030542
2: 652.2841    1.038007
3: 656.0115    1.045524
---
898: 3991.9788   0.154956
899: 3995.7062   0.154487
900: 3999.4335   0.154353

$`file_name_2`
   Wavenumber   Intensity
   <num>        <num>
1: 648.5568     0.996704
2: 652.2841     0.974724
3: 656.0115     0.995108
---
898: 3991.9788   0.031034
899: 3995.7062   0.031093
900: 3999.4335   0.031584

$`file_name_3`
   Wavenumber   Intensity
   <num>        <num>
1: 648.5568     1.140513
2: 652.2841     1.126944
3: 656.0115     1.141629
---
898: 3991.9788   0.058307
899: 3995.7062   0.058664
900: 3999.4335   0.059424

So as you can see, the Wavenumber is the same for all three CSV files, but I want to extract the Intensity column and put them into separate columns in a data frame.
dput output:
> dput(lapply(temp, head))
list(`2024-05-29T09-22-52.csv` = structure(list(Wavenumber = c(648.5568, 
652.2841, 656.0115, 659.7388, 663.4661, 667.1935), Intensity = c(1.030542, 
1.038007, 1.045524, 1.028202, 1.042649, 1.048854)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x15b81e2e0>), 
    `2024-05-29T09-23-53.csv` = structure(list(Wavenumber = c(648.5568, 
    652.2841, 656.0115, 659.7388, 663.4661, 667.1935), Intensity = c(0.996704, 
    0.974724, 0.995108, 1.01785, 0.9991, 0.987941)), row.names = c(NA, 
    -6L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x15b81e2e0>), 
    `2024-05-29T09-24-57.csv` = structure(list(Wavenumber = c(648.5568, 
    652.2841, 656.0115, 659.7388, 663.4661, 667.1935), Intensity = c(1.140513, 
    1.126944, 1.141629, 1.135522, 1.133494, 1.12755)), row.names = c(NA, 
    -6L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x15b81e2e0>), 
    `2024-05-29T09-26-03.csv` = structure(list(Wavenumber = c(648.5568, 
    652.2841, 656.0115, 659.7388, 663.4661, 667.1935), Intensity = c(0.101099, 
    0.102831, 0.102439, 0.099929, 0.102317, 0.101984)), row.names = c(NA, 
    -6L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x15b81e2e0>), 
    `2024-05-29T09-27-41.csv` = structure(list(Wavenumber = c(648.5568, 
    652.2841, 656.0115, 659.7388, 663.4661, 667.1935), Intensity = c(0.340125, 
    0.312485, 0.29313, 0.267709, 0.270271, 0.281804)), row.names = c(NA, 
    -6L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x15b81e2e0>), 
    `2024-05-29T09-28-31.csv` = structure(list(Wavenumber = c(648.5568, 
    652.2841, 656.0115, 659.7388, 663.4661, 667.1935), Intensity = c(0.010274, 
    0.044006, 0.073261, 0.099358, 0.166449, 0.153897)), row.names = c(NA, 
    -6L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x15b81e2e0>), 
    `2024-05-29T09-29-24.csv` = structure(list(Wavenumber = c(648.5568, 
    652.2841, 656.0115, 659.7388, 663.4661, 667.1935), Intensity = c(1.164102, 
    1.139151, 1.130817, 1.140624, 1.155876, 1.148028)), row.names = c(NA, 
    -6L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x15b81e2e0>), 
    `2024-05-29T09-30-15.csv` = structure(list(Wavenumber = c(648.5568, 
    652.2841, 656.0115, 659.7388, 663.4661, 667.1935), Intensity = c(1.093891, 
    1.097682, 1.103796, 1.091059, 1.087348, 1.077016)), row.names = c(NA, 
    -6L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x15b81e2e0>), 
    `2024-05-29T09-31-09.csv` = structure(list(Wavenumber = c(648.5568, 
    652.2841, 656.0115, 659.7388, 663.4661, 667.1935), Intensity = c(1.349859, 
    1.337713, 1.361983, 1.348318, 1.368303, 1.382865)), row.names = c(NA, 
    -6L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x15b81e2e0>), 
    `2024-05-29T09-32-05.csv` = structure(list(Wavenumber = c(648.5568, 
    652.2841, 656.0115, 659.7388, 663.4661, 667.1935), Intensity = c(0.800888, 
    0.799098, 0.797646, 0.78962, 0.791059, 0.786255)), row.names = c(NA, 
    -6L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x15b81e2e0>), 
    `2024-05-29T09-32-58.csv` = structure(list(Wavenumber = c(648.5568, 
    652.2841, 656.0115, 659.7388, 663.4661, 667.1935), Intensity = c(0.648536, 
    0.641816, 0.643132, 0.645919, 0.652091, 0.647734)), row.names = c(NA, 
    -6L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x15b81e2e0>), 
    `2024-05-29T09-33-50.csv` = structure(list(Wavenumber = c(648.5568, 
    652.2841, 656.0115, 659.7388, 663.4661, 667.1935), Intensity = c(0.862066, 
    0.852558, 0.858745, 0.862727, 0.867503, 0.863893)), row.names = c(NA, 
    -6L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x15b81e2e0>), 
    `2024-05-29T09-34-38.csv` = structure(list(Wavenumber = c(648.5568, 
    652.2841, 656.0115, 659.7388, 663.4661, 667.1935), Intensity = c(-0.09001, 
    -0.03768, 0.024454, 0.105274, 0.177033, 0.106877)), row.names = c(NA, 
    -6L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x15b81e2e0>), 
    `2024-05-29T09-35-41.csv` = structure(list(Wavenumber = c(648.5568, 
    652.2841, 656.0115, 659.7388, 663.4661, 667.1935), Intensity = c(0.909866, 
    0.903244, 0.905315, 0.911915, 0.924571, 0.917188)), row.names = c(NA, 
    -6L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x15b81e2e0>), 
    `2024-05-29T09-36-32.csv` = structure(list(Wavenumber = c(648.5568, 
    652.2841, 656.0115, 659.7388, 663.4661, 667.1935), Intensity = c(0.659718, 
    0.652121, 0.652549, 0.653092, 0.657701, 0.654459)), row.names = c(NA, 
    -6L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x15b81e2e0>), 
    `2024-05-29T09-37-31.csv` = structure(list(Wavenumber = c(648.5568, 
    652.2841, 656.0115, 659.7388, 663.4661, 667.1935), Intensity = c(-0.233468, 
    -0.183023, -0.128291, -0.056737, 0.018415, -0.039864)), row.names = c(NA, 
    -6L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x15b81e2e0>))


There are multiple ways to do this, but it would be helpful if you provided some samples of a few of your CSVs. You can provide data by pasting the output of dput(head(<data frame>)) into your post. Most likely you could iterate through the list of data frames, extract the columns you want, and stack them into a single data frame.

@LMc I just added some example code to the original post

Please use dput() it makes it much easier for us to use your example data. Try something like dput(lapply(<list of data frames>, head)).

@LMc updated again with dput

Line count for every single file is 900?

library(dplyr)

bind_cols(list_df) |>
  select(starts_with("Intensity"))

Or in base R
dat <- do.call(cbind, list_df)
dat[, endsWith(names(dat), "Intensity")]


That put all the Intensity columns from each file into one column, is there a way to keep each one separate?
